# How to display the original page cache when there is a query parameter?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I think I solved the first part where it shouldn't cache pages with query parameters using

```
if ( bereq.url ~ "/\?.*$" ){
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    set beresp.ttl = 120s;
    return (deliver);
  }
```

However, that doesn't show the cached version of the original page when visiting the page with queries.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

What should be added to the varnish-vcl configuration to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not sure what you need. Your code is actually leveraging the hit-for-miss capabilities of varnish, but you'd be better of just doing this:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ \?) {
        return (pass);
    }
}
```

The subtle difference in your version, Varnish creates a cache object (just the metadata, actually) for 120 seconds to remember it shouldn't be cached. But as you know from the start you shouldn't cache it, you can just `return (pass)` in `vcl_recv`.

Now, if what you want is stripping the query string so that all requests actually return the main page, you have to do this instead:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.url = reqsub(req.url, "\?.*", "");
}
```

this finds the first question mark and everything right of it and replaces it with nothing, effectively killing the query string.

Comment: 2nd one is the solution. Thanks.